# Graph algebra reference/Explanation

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

Can someone give reference to read more about Graph algebra!

I read that Graph algebra is structure with Graph $G=(V,E)$ where $V$ is vertex set and $E$ is edge set and operation $•$ defined from vertex set of graph to $V \cup \{0\}$as

$u•v=u $ if there is edge between $u$ and $v$, otherwise $0$.
$(0\notin V)$

All i found is this definition and few reasearch paper in which discuss about dualizability and graph algebra, graph and topologies on discrete set and finite bases for flat graph algebras.

I want something that explain what is Graph algebra and where we can use it. Just basic of graph algebra.

Like we have set and define binary operations satisfying certain conditions and we call that structure group and then we study properties of that structure(groups). Similar we have graph and binary operation and we call it graph algebra, what's next? There are properties of graph algebra! I couldn't find anything except definition of graph algebra.

Comment: Could you please share where you found the definition and the research papers? Thanks.

Comment: Sure. I found on Wikipedia here is link https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_algebra and i found papers from it there is section work cited thats all i found.